# HTTP Request error vs response error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

i am looking on [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) interceptors. And i see there is requestError and responseError.

1) What is the difference between requestError and responseError? 
2) In what condition does requestError trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

request Error is an error that have not fulfilled criteria,missing parameters that is required to find a resource on a server like `header` payload missing

response Error is an error that was sent by server according to request which was made to that like `404`  Page not found is a response error

Comment: Btw is 400 bad request consider an request error or response error?

Answer (score 2):

you should take a look to this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

the difference is that requestError means that your request cannot be handled, maybe you have an error with the url or the server is not available

the responseError its related with the http status codes, you reach the server, but there may be something wrong, for example it may be an error with a request that will answer you, but it may be an empty response with the code **204 No Content**

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a request error and a response error is their order in the promise chain built up by the interceptors. Take a look at this [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L986)

> ```
> // apply interceptors
>   forEach(reversedInterceptors, function(interceptor) {
>     if (interceptor.request || interceptor.requestError) {
>       chain.unshift(interceptor.request, interceptor.requestError);
>     }
>     if (interceptor.response || interceptor.responseError) {
>       chain.push(interceptor.response, interceptor.responseError);
>     }
>   });
>
>   while (chain.length) {
>     var thenFn = chain.shift();
>     var rejectFn = chain.shift();
>
>     promise = promise.then(thenFn, rejectFn);
>   }
> ```

So you see that for interceptors which provide all the four methods, you'll get a promise like so:

`promise.then(requestFn, requestErrorFn).then(responseFn, responseErrorFn)`.

To answer 2. the promise is created by `var promise = $q.when(config);` after a request has been initialized. At first glance it get's a bit hairy exactly what's going on, but the config object appears to have some default callbacks.  I presume if there is something wrong with the actual request syntax/config, or angular encounters an issue sending the request (perhaps no network available or something like that), then the original promise will resolve as rejected, and this would cause the `requestError` handler to be invoked.